# How to return the method?

Tags: c#

I need to split it to another function and return see whether it contains some value or not but I'm not so sure how to make it. Example

```
exList = getList(ref Path, type);
if(exList.Count > 0){
  Do something...
}
```

Im not so sure this part how to write... this is my half work

```
        static object getList(ref string Path, string type)
        {

            exList = new List<Email>();
            string[] jsonFileList = Directory.GetFiles(Path, type + "_*.json");
            if (jsonFileList.Length > 0)
            {
                //read json file
                foreach (string file in jsonFileList)
                {
                    if (File.Exists(file))
                    {
                        exList.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExceptionEmail>(File.ReadAllText(file)));

                        File.Delete(file);
                    }
                }
            }
            return something;
        }
```

Comment: I couldn't get properly, but you can create 2 functions and call one function from other function

Comment: I really am not sure what you are asking here, but there's no need to return `object` here, make your method return a `List`.

Comment: 嘗試表達更多 (Try to Express more)

Comment: the main things i want to do is return and check at this part if(List.Count > 0){
  Do something...
}

how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

check below code

```
static List<Email> getList(ref string Path, string type)
        {

            exceptionList = new List<Email>();
            string[] jsonFileList = Directory.GetFiles(Path, type + "_*.json");
            if (jsonFileList.Length > 0)
            {
                //read json file
                foreach (string file in jsonFileList)
                {
                    if (File.Exists(file))
                    {
                        List.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExceptionEmail>(File.ReadAllText(file)));

                        File.Delete(file);
                    }
                }
            }
            return exceptionList;
        }
```

Comment: i have change my code and found that the code after i amend is same with you. I try go run see after that. because above a lot of the path was not exits in my pc. I need create another project and hardcode some path and jsonfile to test the whole code

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to return a list and you need to save the return value into a variable.

```
// not List = ..., List is a class, you need a new instance of a list.
List<Email> list = getList(path, type);
if (list.Count > 0)
{
    // Do Something
}
// [...]
private List<Email> getList(string path, string type)
{
    List<Email> ret = new List<Email>();
    string[] jsonFileList = Directory.GetFiles(path, type + "_*.json");
    if (jsonFileList.Length > 0)
    {
        //read json file
        foreach (string file in jsonFileList)
        {
            if (File.Exists(file))
            {
                // not List.Add(), List is a class, you need to add to the instance of a list.
                ret.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExceptionEmail>(File.ReadAllText(file)));
                // File.Delete(file); // The method shouldn't delete files when it's name is getList, delete them after handling in the calling method.
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Also you should work on your style.

- Please do use strong types wherever possible. (i.E. no Object)
- Try to avoid static functions and variables unless you need them.
- For readability write the access modifier.
- Variable and argument names should be lower case and constants capitals. Only classes, enums and interfaces, structs, etc. should start with a capital letter.
- Only use reference arguments if you need to. Call by value is default for a reason. (The reason being encapsulation, and avoiding side effects. Also you would expect the function here to alter path if you say it's byref, which it doesn't.)
- getList shouldn't delete files. You wouldn't expect that from a name like that. Delete the files AFTER you processed them in the loop in the calling method.
- please review the difference between classes and objects/instances.
- please review function calls and return values.